# Error when calculating MAX values inside a condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This piece of code is giving me this error: **_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

```
df2 = df1.withColumn('DISTANCESTATE', 
      F.when(F.col('DISTANCE') <= F.col('RADIUSINMETERS') + F.col('RADIUSINMETERS2'), "OVERLAP")
                                                          .when(F.col('DISTANCE') >= max(F.col('RADIUSINMETERS'), F.col('RADIUSINMETERS2')), "INSIDE")
.otherwise(' '))

df2.show(1000, False)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `F.greatest` for this purpose. You can't use Python `max` on spark columns.

```
df2 = df1.withColumn('DISTANCESTATE',
    F.when(
        F.col('DISTANCE') <= F.col('RADIUSINMETERS') + F.col('RADIUSINMETERS2'), 
        "OVERLAP"
    ).when(
        F.col('DISTANCE') >= F.greatest(F.col('RADIUSINMETERS'), F.col('RADIUSINMETERS2')), 
        "INSIDE"
   ).otherwise(' ')
)
```